# Remove characters from python output

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, character

I have written a PYTHON code to print recommended product id's having a product id of a certain product. I am getting the output as:-

```
  ['503821321','503821331','504821322','503821343']
```

I want the output to be as:-

```
   503821321, 503821331, 504821322, 503821343
```

What should I do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [77]: ', '.join(['503821321','503821331','504821322','503821343'])
Out[77]: '503821321, 503821331, 504821322, 503821343'

In [78]: print(', '.join(['503821321','503821331','504821322','503821343']))
503821321, 503821331, 504821322, 503821343
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foo = ['503821321','503821331','504821322','503821343']
','.join(i for i in foo)
```

Output:

```
'503821321,503821331,504821322,503821343'
```

Comment: Perhaps just  `','.join(foo)`